# RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may lead to deadlocks

Tags: react-native

I get this in logs:

> RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RCTDevLoadingView. This may
>   lead to deadlocks

This is leading to an issue where the rendered content in React leads to alignment issues.

(See attached screenshot 1) [Screenshot with Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK0vC.png)

This occurs randomly as all screens do not show alignment issues.

(See attached Screenshot 2) [Screenshot without issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGvzR.png)

I have used styled-components for Layout:

```
return(
  this.props.lastComponent ?
  <CommentList marginLeft={this.props.marginLeft}>
    <CommentUserPicWrapper imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth}>
      {this.props.imageType === 'URL' ? <CommentUserPic source={{uri:this.props.uri}} imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth} onLoad={this.handleLoad}/> : <CommentUserPic source={require('../../img/defaultProfPic.png')} imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth} onLoad={this.handleLoad}/>}
      {
        this.state.loading ? null : <ActivityIndicator style={{position:'absolute'}}/>
      }
    </CommentUserPicWrapper>
    <CommentDetails borderStatus={true} marginLeft={this.props.marginLeft}>
      <CommentUserName>{this.props.userName} says</CommentUserName>
      <CommentUserContent>{this.props.UserContent}</CommentUserContent>
      <CommentUserDate><Text>{this.props.commentDate}</Text> at <Text>{this.props.commentTime}</Text>MST</CommentUserDate>
    </CommentDetails>
    <CommentReply onPress={this.replyClicked} borderStatus={true} underlayColor='transparent'>
      <CommentReplyText>Reply</CommentReplyText>
    </CommentReply>
  </CommentList>
  :
  <CommentList marginLeft={this.props.marginLeft}>
    <CommentUserPicWrapper imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth}>
      {this.props.imageType === 'URL' ? <CommentUserPic source={{uri:this.props.uri}} imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth} onLoad={this.handleLoad}/> : <CommentUserPic source={require('../../img/defaultProfPic.png')} imageWidth={this.props.imageWidth} onLoad={this.handleLoad}/>}
      {this.state.loading ? null : <ActivityIndicator style={{position:'absolute'}}/>}
    </CommentUserPicWrapper>
    <CommentDetails borderStatus={this.props.borderStatus} marginLeft={this.props.marginLeft}>
      <CommentUserName>{this.props.userName} says</CommentUserName>
      <CommentUserContent>{this.props.UserContent}</CommentUserContent>
      <CommentUserDate><Text>{this.props.commentDate}</Text> at <Text>{this.props.commentTime}</Text>MST</CommentUserDate>
    </CommentDetails>
    <CommentReply onPress={this.replyClicked} borderStatus={this.props.borderStatus} underlayColor='transparent'>
      <CommentReplyText>Reply</CommentReplyText>
    </CommentReply>
  </CommentList>
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Have shared the render method I have used in the Code

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? For me, setting `inlineRequire` to true fixes it but causes other errors

Answer (score 66):

I fixed it with updating `AppDelegate.m` as below:

```objectivec
   #if RCT_DEV
   #import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
   #endif
   //...

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
   //...
   RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                 moduleProvider:nil
                  launchOptions:launchOptions];
   #if RCT_DEV
   [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
   #endif

   RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                    moduleName:@"<AddYourAppNameHere>"
                 initialProperties:nil];
   //...
   }
```

Source:
*grossingdev's* answer Dec 10, 2017 from: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16376

Comment: Is this solving the cause of the warning is it masking it for development builds?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working anymore in 2022

Answer (score 14):

Add this line right after you import AppDelegate.h

```
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif
```

And then in the implementation of AppDelegate right before RCTRootView add the below lines:

```
#if RCT_DEV
[bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
```

Rebuild the app now. The error should be gone.

For further reference, visit [here](https://amanhimself.dev/blog/rctbridge-required-dispatch-sync-to-load-warning/).

Comment: worked for me using RN 0.62.2

Comment: doesn't work any longer after upgrading to 0.63.5

Answer (score 6):

some answers corrected but not clearly for somebody read. Because Delegate.h not easy for newbie

1. location: PRODUCT_NAME/product_name/AppDelegate.m
2. Edit that file carefully because if you wrong anything that will build fail or sometime when you reload your project will be build fail (so must be carefully):
   **in first file after** #import "AppDelegate.h"

> #import "AppDelegate.h"
>
> // Add this

> #if RCT_DEV
> #import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
> #endif // ---------------

**add Before** RCTRootView *rootView =

> // add this

> #if RCT_DEV
> [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];

> #endif   //-------------------
> RCTRootView *rootView = .... (your default code)

Answer (score 3):

When using [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/), modify your AppDelegate.m file like this:

```objectivec
// Add this
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

// ...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrapWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

// Add this
#if RCT_DEV
  [[ReactNativeNavigation getBridge] moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
  
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation and/or source?

Answer (score 1):

Swift Solution

```
let bridge = RCTBridge(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleProvider: nil, launchOptions: nil)

#if RCT_DEV
bridge?.module(for: RCTDevLoadingView.self)
#endif
let rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge!, moduleName: "AppMain", initialProperties: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    If you just connect your app to a Firebase instance. then update your AppDelegate.m with 
   (in Objective C)  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application customDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     if(![FIRApp defaultApp]){
        [FIRApp configure];}}
    } 
    instead of just adding [FIRApp configure];

(in Swift) func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    return true
  }
```