# Getting error RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RNGestureHandlerModule. This may lead to deadlocks

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the same error as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988103/rctbridge-required-dispatch-sync-to-load-rctdevloadingview-this-may-lead-to-dea)

However rather than **RCTDevLoadingView** mine is referring to **RNGestureHandlerModule**.
Similar to the issue linked above, my guess is that it's something related to making an update in the appdelegate.m file, however I cant figure out what that entails.

I'm using react-native 0.67.1 and react-native-gesture-handler 2.2.0.

Thank you

Comment: Try this https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/722#issuecomment-1014289859

Answer (score 14):

##### UPDATE: the issue was fixed in version 2.8.0

So if you do not depend on the old versions, just run

`npm install react-native-reanimated@latest`

or `yarn add react-native-reanimated@latest`.

Then `cd ios && pod install`

###### Old answer:

Change `react-native-reanimated` version to `~2.2.4` in package.json, then run

`npm install` or `yarn install`

`cd ios && pod install`

The answer was got from [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/722#issuecomment-1014289859)

Comment: Legend, thank you. I tried upvoting but i dont have 15 reputation yet, will come back to it :)

Comment: That fix it for me! I was on the version before `~2.4.0`.
I didn't test on `~2.3.0`. (Maybe i could works too?)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be fixed in 2.8.0:

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/commit/d6c73042900767e4065284cc39970c2fe0d73a97

This did, in fact, cause deadlocks for me like the warning said it could.  (So it's nice that it's actually fixed instead of them just trying to hide the warning and making it harder to debug.  Fortunately it didn't hide it in the Xcode console, or this would have been a real nightmare...)

Comment: Indeed, it fixes the issue, no need to downgrade, latest one already has the solution. Thanks for pointing it out.