# RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RNGestureHandlerModule. This may lead to deadlocks

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I begun to get this warning after installing `"react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0"` package that's required by other package for web (my app also supports a web platform).

[image: Screenshot]

Of course, I went to goole for questions with the same problem, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70175201/3253896). I followed all instructions from the answer and have changed `AppDelegate.m` as below:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// Fix 1
#if RCT_DEV
#import <React/RCTDevLoadingView.h>
#endif

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *Letopeace = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [Letopeace addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [Letopeace addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [Letopeace addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [Letopeace addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [Letopeace start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
// Fix 2
#if RCT_DEV
  [bridge moduleForClass:[RCTDevLoadingView class]];
#endif
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Letopeace"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

However, it doesn't work, I am still getting the warning:

```
RCTBridge required dispatch_sync to load RNGestureHandlerModule. This may lead to deadlocks
```

Where can the problem be?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is related RNGH first upgrade your RNGH and then pass the following code to App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';




const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        <AuthTokenProvider>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            initialRouteName="SplashScreen">
            <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Flow" component={Flow} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </AuthTokenProvider>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank You